# MySQL: CMS with versionig system

Tags: mysql

I built a simple CMS. Each row of the main table *pages* contains all the information for a single page and has two fields relevant for this question:

*page_id*: an indexed, varchar, not unique field
*last_update*: a unix timestamp

What MySQL query would retrieve the row of a specific page_id which has the biggest *last_update* value?

Comment: Perhaps, just - `select * from mytable where page_id = 'page1' order by last_update desc limit 1`. It might be a good idea to add a unique index on `(page_id, last_update)` and ditch the existing single column index on `page_id`.

Comment: Who can I ask for more details on what is meant by "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only"? The question was answered to my full satisfaction by @SelVazi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inner join` and `group by` with `max()` :

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
  select page_id, max(last_update) as max_last_update
  from mytable
  where page_id = 'page1'
  group by page_id
) as s on s.page_id = t.page_id and s.max_last_update = t.last_update
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/PjQohUKa)

Comment: This is great, thank you very much @SelVazi. This answers my question fully